# What are the main and non-damaging parts of Sysinternals Autoruns?

Tags: sysinternals

What are the main parts of [Sysinternals Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) to use when disabling regular startup items that I can tell a not-so technical user to use? (Not parts for disabling stuff like important services etc.)

Comment: Tell him/her to leave it alone

Answer (score 1):

All tabs can become dangerous because the user might disable some functionality or stop windows from booting at all, but if he want to learn he should start with the tabs `Login Explorer` and `Internet Explorer` in any case he should google every unknown entry.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that it would probably be best to ask the user to export or save the output from Autoruns, then send it to me, and then I would tell the user exactly what to disable or enable.